# Categorical Feature Embedding When a Specific Feature Can be Present in Multiple Fields

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow, categorical-encoding, keras

**Goal**: I own a restaurant that specializes in spaghetti, and I want to build a neural network that predicts overall customer satisfaction (output variable) of different spaghetti sauce recipes, based on all of the factors that go into spaghetti sauce (e.g., ingredients, cooking temperature, cook time).

**Question**: I would like to use Categorical Feature Embeddings to represent the different ingredients that go into the spaghetti sauce in each recipe, but because there is no domain-specific reason to order the ingredients in any manner, I'm not sure how to correctly generate the Categorical Feature Embedding vectors for each ingredient.

**Example**: Let's say that I consistently have three ingredients that I toss in the sauce **at the same time** in the cooking process: `[<ingredient1>, <ingredient2>, <ingredient3>]` and the total options of ingredients are:

`['sweet sausage', 'ground beef', 'white onion', 'red onion', 'garlic', 'clove']`

Some specific scenarios would be:

`['sweet sausage', 'white onion', 'garlic']`

`['clove', 'ground beef', 'red onion']`

`['clove', 'white onion', 'garlic']`

`['white onion', 'ground beef', 'clove']`

`['sweet sausage', 'ground beef', 'clove']`

In the last example above, there is no domain-specific reason to not order the ingredients like `['ground beef', 'clove', 'sweet sausage']` instead.

I would like to create a Categorical Feature Embedding numeric vector to represent each unique ingredient. But because there is no domain-specific reason to order the ingredient combinations in any particular way, I'm interested in learning different approaches of how others would go about transforming the data to feed into a Tensforflow model for feature embedding if each ingredient has the possibility of landing in any of the three `ingredient` fields of the dataset.

**Disclosure**: The example above is a total made-up scenario to illustrate my problem. I am not a great cook and you probably wouldn't want to eat my spaghetti sauce, regardless of the ingredient combination. :)

Comment: My first thought was to use a transformer model without position embeddings. I believe that would even be a pretty good approach, even if you had a flexible number of ingredients rather than the fixed number of 3.

Comment: @Björn thanks for the response. I'm not very familiar with transformers, so a couple of follow-up questions: can you incorporate a Transformer model into a larger feed-forward network that incorporates other numeric variables (like cooking temperature) to return a soft-max probability output of customer responses ('does not like', 'neutral', and 'likes')?

Additionally, I would still need to generate a meaningful vector representation (embedding) of each ingredient to feed into the self-attention layer, correct?

Comment: Yes, no reason why not, it's not exactly a transformer anymore, but the encoder part of it for the categories + attention to "decide" what to "pay attention to" in the inputs. Tbf, with just 3 inputs, 3 inputs with the same embeddings & using the permutations of ingredients as data augmentation (for once we know how to augment for tabular data!) is also an option. In either case, you can learn the embeddings from scratch when training in a supervised way. You could also try unsupervised pre-training (e.g. mask 1 of 3 ingredients & ask the model to predict it - look e.g. at BERT pre-training).